# Sharing a file over network and deny deletion

Tags: microsoft-excel, permissions, network-shares, read-only

I have an EXCEL file that I want to share on the network on Windows 7.
I want everyone to access it on the network but prevent them from deleting it except me.
I wanted to do that through the permissions tab but all the checkboxes under ALLOW are checked and could not be unchecked.
Is there an effective solution for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the checkboxes under ALLOW are checked and could not be unchecked

When permission inheritance is turned on, the permissions are set to match the parent folder's permissions, and you can't edit them (except by editing the permissions on the parent).

Turn off permission inheritance for the file/folder in question, so that you can edit the permissions for that file/folder independently and apply the permissions you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and click properties

Click the security tab then click advanced

Click change permissions and choose or add the group you want to edit permissions on (you would normally want to create a new security group for accessing this file with these permissions instead of using individual or built-in accounts and this would be done in Active Directory if you are on a domain)

Add all the permission you want to give them and where it says Delete check the box under Deny

Then click OK and apply